# Thread safety of the ambient LogContext in Serilog

Tags: c#, serilog

According to [this](https://nblumhardt.com/2016/08/context-and-correlation-structured-logging-concepts-in-net-5/) article, you can attach a request ID to an ambient context (the `LogContext`) in Serilog like this:

```
using (LogContext.PushProperty("RequestId", Request.Id))
{
    // Process request; all logged events will carry `RequestId`
    Log.Information("Adding {Item} to cart {CartId}", item, cart.Id);
}
```

And that is fine, and seems to be working. I have two scenarios where I need this:

- Add a correlation ID to logs per request to an API.
- Add a correlation ID per message read of a queue.

What has me confused is what happens if multiple requests hits the API at once, or we process multiple messages concurrently. Since `LogContext` is a static class, can I accidentally overwrite the `RequestId` property in the `LogContext` with values from another thread than the one who originally set the property?

Lets say thread 1 sets the `RequestId` to `1`. Before it is finished, thread 2 sets the `RequestId` to `2` because we received another request. Will thread 1 now use `2` as the value for `RequestId` when logging? I'm guessing it wont, but can someone explain why? According this [this](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Enrichment), pushing a property with the same name as an existing property onto the stack overwrites it:

> Pushing property onto the context will override any existing properties with the same name, until the object returned from PushProperty() is disposed, as the property A in the example demonstrates.

Does Serilog have one stack per handle returned from the `LogContext.PushProperty(...)` method, or something? Is there any way I can override `RequestId`, perhaps short of calling `LogContext.PushProperty("RequestId", Request.Id)` again?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[LogContext is thread-safe via AsyncLocal/ThreadStatic](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/blob/5e2164756efb6023a548b4eb91a71ed7edc3d9e1/src/Serilog/Context/LogContext.cs#L54-L61). Each thread has their own LogContext despite it being accessed through a static class. Requests don't share the same LogContext.

Comment: Wow, this means we should dispose the pushed property to avoid polluting other parts of the same thread.

Comment: LogContext.PushProperty returns an IDisposable so yes you should.